# Network outputs from tf.session.run greatly differ from the ones obtained with keras.Model.predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use Keras model through Tensorflow session. But results form `model.predict` and `sess.run` different. Is there any way to work with Kers model through Tensorflow session?

> Tensorflow version: 1.4.0
>   Keras version: 2.1.1

```py
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_circles
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

sess = tf.Session()
K.tensorflow_backend.set_session(sess)

X, y = make_circles(n_samples=1000,
                    noise=0.1,
                    factor=0.2,
                    random_state=0)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(2,), activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(SGD(lr=0.5), 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=20)

print("Keras model. First prediction: " + str(model.predict(np.c_[0, 0])))
print("Keras model. Second prediction: " + str(model.predict(np.c_[1.5, 1.5])))

with sess.as_default():

    y_tensor = model.outputs[0]
    x_tensor = model.inputs[0]
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print("TF model. First prediction: " + str(sess.run(y_tensor, feed_dict={x_tensor: np.c_[0, 0]} )))
    print("TF model. Second prediction: " + str(sess.run(y_tensor, feed_dict={x_tensor: np.c_[1.5, 1.5]} )))
```

Comment: Better to use `tf.keras` directly instead of this kind of flow. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, it's `K.set_session(s)` and not `K.tensorflow_backend.set_session(s)`.

Second: `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` resets all variables using their respective initializer, including the network weights (they use `xavier` initializer by default).

So you are:

> 1. Training the keras model
> 2. Printing the prediction for the keras model
> 3. Reseting to random weights
> 4. Printing the predictions for the same model

Commenting `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` fixes the problem:

```py
Keras model. First prediction: [[ 0.99195099]]
Keras model. Second prediction: [[ 0.03110269]]
TF model. First prediction: [[ 0.99195099]]
TF model. Second prediction: [[ 0.03110269]]
```